# using libFLAC to convert the output of AudioContext to FLAC format

Tags: html, audio, flac, webkitaudiocontext

I am trying to convert the PCM output of HTML5 audiocontext (e.g. `buffer.getChannelData(0)`, ...) to PCM data that is required by "FLAC__stream_encoder_process_interleaved"

The weird thing is FLAC requires data as int32 buffer (`const FLAC__int32 buffer[]`) however the output of audiocontext is normalized float32 array. I am not sure how to convert the normalized buffer of audio context to the format that FLAC requires.

[Link](https://xiph.org/flac/api/group__flac__stream__encoder.html#ga64)

Can somebody explain why FLAC needs the buffer in int32 instead of common float32 array?

Answer (score 0):

Well. I've written an C# FLAC decoder some time ago and because the documentation does not cover eveything, I had to read a few parts of the code of libFlac. Int32 gets used internally quite often. I don't know a good reason except performance improvments. int32 ist faster than using floats. But if you've got ieeefloat samples you can simple multiply them by [(2^BitsPerSample) / 2] to get your integers. Why the output is float32. I don't know. All in all the code of the library is quite strange and often quite hard to unterstand the developers concepts.